# Are there any websites (or tools) in which I could translate Early Modern English into Present Day English?

Tags: discussion

I'm an English Learner who is interested in the Early Modern English recently. I have some texts from EModE to read. Sometimes there are words and grammar patterns that I can't relate to Present Day English. I need help with them.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You mean like Google Translate, but with an Early Modern English option? I'd be surprised (for technical reasons - lack of training data). It's not really that hard to read, though, with a good dictionary, a book on the history of the English Language, and ideally well-annotated texts. There isn't much difference in grammar, but there is in how some words are used.

Comment: Try: https://lingojam.com/EarlyModerntoModernEnglish

Comment: @StuartF There is a difference in vocabulary too: I recently had to Tudorise a text which included the word *personified.* While the metaphorical concept existed for, say, Shakespeare, the **word itself** was only coined in around 1730. For the phrase "the Divine Mercy personified" I ended up with "who did embody in his person the Divine Mercy". (But that's merely an illustration; this question is not the place to critique that phrase!)

Comment: @user66974 thanks, but i tried it, but no really working. I guess there is no such tool.

Comment: @StuartF That is what i meant!

Comment: You're better off looking for adapted /simplified versions for learners of English. You can use My Shakespeare or Spark notes online to find modern-day versions of Shakespeare  https://myshakespeare.com/macbeth/act-1-scene-1-full-scene-modern-english and https://www.sparknotes.com/nofear/shakespeare/macbeth/act-1-scene-1/

Comment: https://www.shakespeareswords.com/Public/Glossary.aspx